# Mbuni: mms submitted properly but images not getting download

Tags: mms, kannel, smil, mms-gateway

I am using mbuni for sending mms as smil content by http url by

```
content-type=application/smil
```

and

```
content-url=http://localhost/TestSmil.smil
```

Right now mms getting submitted to handset but images are not getting download.

```
    group = core
    log-file = /tmp/mms/log/mmsbox.log
    access-log = /tmp/mms/log/mmsbox-access.log
    log-level = 0

    group = mbuni
    storage-directory = /var/spool/mbuni
    max-send-threads = 5
    maximum-send-attempts = 1
    default-message-expiry = 360000
    queue-run-interval = 5
    send-attempt-back-off = 300
    sendmms-port = 10001
    content-adaptation = false
    allow-adaptations = 0

    group = mmsc
    id = 123456
    mmsc-url = http://123456:MYVASID@<MMSC_IP>:8080/vas_soap
    incoming-username = 123456
    incoming-password = PWD
    incoming-port = 12345
    type = soap
    default-vasid = MYVASID
    content-adaptation = false
    allow-adaptations = 0

    group = send-mms-user
    username = tester
    password = foobar
    faked-sender = 100
    allow-adaptations = 0
```

URL of mmsbox

```
    http://localhost:10001/cgi-bin/sendmms?username=tester&password=*****&from=12345&to=9199********&subject=TestMMS&allow-adaptations=0&content-adaptation=false&vasid=123456&content-type=application%2Fsmil&content-url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmms%2FTestSmil.smil
```

Smile file content and path

```
    <smil>
      <body>
        <seq repeatCount="indefinite">
          <img src="image1.jpg" dur="3s" />
          <img src="image2.jpg" dur="3s" />
        </seq>
      </body>
    </smil>
```

Path is /var/www/html/mms/. also i have changed image path from image1.jpg to mms/image1.jpg but no change.

If I am sending direct images like content-url=http://localhost/image1.jpg it's coming properly.

Comment: Please help to solve this..

Comment: Shouldn't you have SMIL header with regions defined ?
Check example here: http://www.nowsms.com/mms-smil-tutorial